so im trying to make a battle code and i want it to show what the user inputs, EX: user enters F code outputs FIGHT
what i need to do is get it to show what you input i have tried changing a few tings but im still new to this so I don't truly know what to do can anyone help me. here is the code
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

using namespace std;

 int F;
 int C;
 int E;
 int Q;
 char c;
 char FIGHT;
 char CAST_SPELL;
 char EVADE;
 char QUIT;
 int UNKNOWN;


  cout << "What would you like to do?";
  cout <<  "  \n[F]ight";
  cout <<  "  \n[C]ast spell";
  cout <<  "  \n[E]vade and Run away";
  cout <<  "  \n[Q]uit\n";
  cin >> c;
  switch (toupper( c ))
    {
    case 'F': return "FIGHT";
    case 'C': return "CAST_SPELL";
    case 'E': return "EVADE";
    case 'Q': return "QUIT";
    }
  return UNKNOWN;
  }


What resources are you using to learn C++? I suggest you go back to the very beginning and the first "hello world" type program it should show. Don't skip anything when you read, and do all exercises. If you don't have a a good book I recommend you invest in one or two. If you're serious about learning C++, the high cost will be well worth it in the future.

Good advice from @Some programmer dude. Here, you should change return "FIGHT"; to cout << "FIGHT";  break;, and make similar changes to the other return statements. Also, #include <stdio.h> can be deleted. return UNKNOWN; should be return 0;

@tbxfreeware: I believe return UNKNOWN; should be cout << "UNKNOWN";. However, it would probably be more meaningful to use a default: label in the switch statement.

I have fixed your code here. As you can see, most of your variable declarations are unnecessary, and you should not be using a return statement for printing, unless you plan to do something like this.

"is there a way to stop the letter they type to not appear" -- That is not possible in standard C++. However, most platforms offer platform-specific features which allows this. For example, on Linux, you can use ncurses and on Windows you can use _getch() or ReadConsoleInput.

thank  you is there a way to do it in your web-browser? if not I can just use my PC for it, this is my school Chromebook so no Linux and no windows

"Is there a way to repeat the code every time they type a unknown letter/number" -- Yes, that is possible by using a loop, for example like this.

@hypergames17y: ChromeOS is a Linux-based operating system, so my guess is that using the ncurses library should also be possible on your Chromebook. However, learning that library would probably not be easy for you until you have more experience. Therefore, I suggest that you don't worry about the input being echoed back to the screen for now.

with all of the school restrictions Linux is blocked i cant download anything, i just have  web-browsing

@hypergames17y: It is possible that the ncurses library is already installed on your Chromebook, so you wouldn't have to download anything. However, as previously stated, I think you should not worry about ncurses for now, and should just accept the input being echoed back to the screen.

@Andreas Wenzel return UNKNOWN; should be cout << "UNKNOWN"; Right you are. I added the bit about UNKNOWN hurriedly, trying to beat the 5-minute edit clock for comments!

@user24500599: You already are handling the case of 'F' inside the switch statement. In the code I gave you, this case is handled by simply printing "FIGHT\n", however, you can tell your program to do anything you want in this case, for example to call a function instead. What is it exactly that you want to accomplish?

What you're describing is what I want to do if you could explain like how to do it or show me how to do it I would be very appreciative

@hypergames17y: Is this what you want? I changed your code so that three functions are being defined, handle_fight, handle_cast_spell and handle_evade. The switch statement will call one of these functions, depending on which key was pressed. You can write any code that you want in these functions.

So I've encountered a new problem I am trying to get it to go back to the main battle screen pretty much once it does the attack and I don't know how to get it to repeat that can someone explain how I can do that                                                                                  if you want me to post the code i think i can post it in segments  or maybe link it

@hypergames17y: I would have to see your code to understand what you are attempting to do. Please don't overwrite your question, as this will invalidate all comments. It is sufficient if you provide a link to your code, for example on this site. Normally, you should start a new question and provide the code in the question, but if you do that, your question will probably be closed due to this guideline. Therefore, it would probably be best if you only ask me in a comment.

@hypergames17y: Note that you will probably learn C++ more effectively if you follow the guidance of a good book (Beginner's level), and do the exercises of the book in the recommended order. Trying to write your own program before you have learnt how to use the necessary building blocks will make it harder for you to learn.

Although you are using a C++ compiler, your style of programming seems to be more C than C++. If you used the printf function instead of cout and removed some unnecessary lines, then your program would also compile as C code. Therefore, if you want to keep that style of programming, you may want to learn C instead of C++. In that case, you may want to first learn the programming language C. In order to learn C, instead of buying a book, you could also do the online CS50 course, which is free. After doing that, writing your text game will be a lot easier.

no, so the thing is i'm trying to do way too complicated stuff for what I know , i am learning C++ but I'm still technically in the basics I'm just learning bits and pieces of complicated stuff from others and shoving it all together.
